# converting type button to submit with ajax and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Problem: When I clicked the button type="button" it displays all data. But if I change it to type="submit" it doesn't displays the data. What I want is to convert this type="button" to type="submit" that would display data.

here's my code:

```
<form name="chatform">
                               <div class="input-group" id="msg">
                                   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputmsg" placeholder="Enter message here. . ." id="inputmsg">
                                   <span class="input-group-btn">
                                      <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" name="btn-send" id="cnd" onClick="submitChat()">Send</button>
                                   </span>
                               </div>
                           </form>
```

ajax w/ jquery

```
function submitChat(){
            if(chatform.inputmsg.value== ""){
                alert("fill in blanks");
                return;
              }
              var msg = chatform.inputmsg.value;
              var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
              xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if(xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status==200){
                  document.getElementById("chatlogs").innerHTML = xhttp.reponseText ? xhttp.reponseText : "";
                }
              };
              xhttp.open("GET","insert.php?msg="+msg, true);
              xhttp.send();
              $(document).ready(function(){
                $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
                setInterval(function(){
                  $("#chatlogs").load("logs.php");
                }, 2000);
              });
              document.getElementById("inputmsg").value = "";
        }
```

Comment: try changing `function submitChat()` to `function submitChat(e)` and on the first row inside the function run `e.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to stop the normal execution of submit. This is the final code:

```
$("#inputmsg").keypress(function(e){
    if(e.which == 13){
        e.preventDefault();
        submitChat();
    }
});

$("#cnd").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    submitChat();
});

function submitChat(){
    if(chatform.inputmsg.value== ""){
        alert("fill in blanks");
        return;
    }
    var msg = chatform.inputmsg.value;
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status==200){
            document.getElementById("chatlogs").innerHTML = xhttp.reponseText ? xhttp.reponseText : "";
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET","insert.php?msg="+msg, true);
    xhttp.send();
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
        setInterval(function(){
            $("#chatlogs").load("logs.php");
        }, 2000);
    });
    document.getElementById("inputmsg").value = "";
}
```

Then remove click function in html button:

```
<button class="btn btn-success" type="button" name="btn-send" id="cnd">Send</button>
```

This should be solve your issue.

Comment: Whoa! Just like I said in my comment!

Comment: @PhiterFernandes Sorry! I did not see your comment! :-(

Comment: In those cases when you don't know exactly what may be causing a behavior, you must comment before posting an answer that may not be the right one. Even if in this case yours is correct.

Comment: You are right but I work every day with jQuery, html, etc and I was pretty sure. Often I happened to forget `e.preventDefault()` at the first writing :-)

Comment: @erikscandola sir i have change it. But it doesn't display anything

Comment: @DumDumDummy Sorry. I changed answer and it works now. My fault. If you need to maintain your function you can maintain it writing this code in click event: `$("#cnd").click(function(){ e.preventDefault(); submitChat(); });`

Comment: @erikscandola what happened is still the same sir. still doesn't display output

Comment: Very strange. I tested and it works fine for me. When textbox is empy I can see an alert otherwise, in console, I can see a 404 error when it try to perform the request but this is correct in my case. In your case, button always do submit?

Comment: @erikscandola when i hit enter displays nothing alert nothing.

Comment: Mmmm... I created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tgca0evj/) where you can try and check for difference between my code and your. I hope it helps

Comment: sir @erikscandola. try putting your cursor on the textbox then press enter it will not do anything. what i want is either i clicked the submit button or click enter it will output something. but this when i clicked button submit doesn't also display something. :(

Comment: Now I understand!! Ok, soon I will update my answer. But please, be more specific next :-)

Comment: @erikscandola its okay now sir . thanks. what my problem again is out of this topic. when pressing enter to perform that function also is another. its handler type :)

Comment: No problem @DumDumDummy :-) I updated the answer and also [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tgca0evj/3/).

Comment: its all okay now :) thanks @erikscandola.. and all stackoverflow